# When should I prefix names with the project name?

Tags: naming, prefix

If you work with SharePoint, you'll see classes like `SPList`, `SPSite` etc.

I've seen variations of this on other projects, in other technologies, e.g. for a CRM project, classes named `CRMLoggingFactory`, `CRMEntity` etc.

This stands out when you look at the code and you know what the prefix corresponds to, but when do you draw the line? What are the conditions for a class to be prefixed by the project name, company name, etc. (i.e. the "domain name" of the project)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will at least partly depend on the language. Id say it is, in general, bad practice in languages that provide proper namespace facilities but good practice in languages that don't.

Answer (score 3):

This is an indication that the environment has weak namespacing facilities, in Java, C++ or C# this is a tautology and a serious code smell. In C with a flat namespace this would be acceptable for public facing API functions.

Comment: Java Swing prefixes its classes with "J" (JPanel, JComponent, JButton, etc.). Would you say this is a serious code smell? Or is it acceptable for some reason in this case? What would that reason be?

Comment: need >=15 characters to say **never**

Comment: Jarrod, I'm not sure I understand your response. I didn't ask a question of "when", which would take an answer like "never". Are you saying that the prefixes in Swing are a serious code smell and the Java team made a mistake because they should never use a project prefix? Or am I missing something? I know I may sound ignorant in this, but I do appreciate the answers!

Comment: [tautology: needless repetition of an idea, especially in words other than those of the immediate context, without imparting additional force or clearness, as in “widow woman.”.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tautology)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the line should be drawn when the class name seems somewhat generic but has a very particular implementation and meaning that is specific to the containing library/framework/api. Also if the library/api/whatever is *expected* to be used in the context with other compenents that may have classes with similar or identical names. You could also use namespaces to help with such problems, but that may not be available in all languages/environments.